# NetLogo : make certain turtles not move at all or stop moving

Tags: netlogo

I want certain turtles in NetLogo to just not move at all AND I want other certain turtles to stop moving.
I have created 5 black turtles which I do not want to move at all and I tried something like
`ask turtles with [color = black] [fd 0]` but that won't work, they still move like the green turtles, which currently is `fd 1`.

I also need `n-of` green turtles to stop moving in the middle of the simulation and I have NO idea how to do that. The `n-of` could also be replaced with a slider.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the part of your code where you have:

```
ask turtles [ fd 1 ]
```

change it to

```
ask turtles with [color != black] [ fd 1 ]
```

As for "I also need n-of green turtles to stop moving in the middle of the simulation", consider an approach such as:

```
turtles-own [velocity]

to setup
  ...
  ;; make some green turtles that move
  create-turtles 10 [ set color green set velocity 1 ]
  ;; make some black turtles that don't move
  create-turtles 10 [ set color black set velocity 0 ]
  ...
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ...
  ;; make some green turtles stop moving
  ask n-of 5 turtles with [color = green] [
    set velocity 0
  ]
  ...
  ask turtles [ fd velocity ]
  ...
  tick
end
```

Make sense?

Comment: Looks like the second part could work, I'll try later, thank you!
I tried the first part where the black turtles should not move before with the same code you suggested, but that didn't work.. They were still moving.